# How do I get the time to save to a file using StreamWriter and DateTime in Unity (I'm using c#)?

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, streamwriter

I've tried adding to the time but it doesn't seem to auto update. I was able to somewhat get the date right but it doesn't change automatically. Here is the code I am using:

```
public int year; 
public int day;
public int hour;
public int minute;
public int seconds;
DateTime dt;

void Start(){
    dt = new DateTime (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);
}

StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter (@"Assets\Time_Stamp.txt");
try(){
    swriter.WritLine(dt.Date.ToString());
    swriter.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex = new Exception("An error has occurred!!");
}
```

How do I fix this to be more automatic and closer to the local time?

Comment: If it's not for direct human consumption, I'd recommend not using local time. Say you store the local time at 1 November 2015, 01:15 in New York. You wouldn't know which 01:15 it was, while if you'd recorded that it was 05:15 UTC or 06:15 UTC you'd be able to work out it was 01:15 local, but also know whether another file with 01:20 local was before or after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Date` property will only return the date part of the `DateTime`, so you would always get 00:00:00 from the `dt`

```
// dt.Date.ToString()
dt.ToString()
```

You will also need to construct your `DateTime` with parameters other than uninitialized int (`0`'s). If you need the current time, consider using :

```
dt = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` does not automatically update after it's been created. `DateTime.Now` static property, which returns current time and date, is what you're looking for. So, basically, you don't need all that `year, month,` etc. variables. 
Also `DateTime` contains a few different methods converting to string, you might want to try them out.

```
swriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
// writes 2015-06-30 23:54:53, but it might look different for you, because it depends on regional settings
swriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
// 23:54:53
swriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
// 30 czerwca 2015 - again dependent on your regional settings
swriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
// 23:54
swriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
// 2015-06-30
```